# How to find elements whose sibling index is less than x and greater than y

Tags: java, jsoup

I have some Element *eNews*. After finding indexes by CssQuery I have to select sibling elements with index less than y and greater than x;

```
Elements lines = eNews.select("div.clear");

int x = lines.get(0).elementSiblingIndex();
int y = lines.get(1).elementSiblingIndex();

Elements tNews = eNews.getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(x) 
                 ?AND? 
                 eNews.getElementsByIndexLessThan(y)
```

This is some sample code. I want to extract text from html tags between first and second `<div class="clear></div>`

```
<div class="aktualnosci">

 <div class="zd">
  <a href="/Data/Thumbs/ODAweDYwMA,dsc_0458.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox">
   <img src="/Data/Thumbs/dsc_0458.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <p class="show"></p>
 </div>
 <h3>Awanse</h3>
 <div class="data">
  <img alt="" src="/Themes/kalendarz-ico.gif">
2013-11-18 12:26
 </div>

 <!--Start tag-->
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <!--Tags to extract-->
 <p class="gr">W związku z Narodowym Świętem Niepodległości ....</p>
 <p style="text-align: justify">W zeszły p....</p>
 <p style="text-align: justify">OISW Kraków</p>

 <!--End tag-->
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="slider">
  <span class="slide-left"></span>
  <span class="slide-right"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a selector like `div.clear ~ :gt(1):lt(4)`

E.g.:

```
Elements tNews = eNews.select("div.clear ~ :gt(1):lt(4)");
```

See [this example](http://try.jsoup.org/~yvH-4nXaaIqHHAdD7HKZgRA7Gak) and the [selector docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). (It's a bit hard to validate this does what you're trying to achieve without knowing your input HTML and the data you're trying to extract.)

**Update** based on your edit: there are a couple ways to do this if you can't know the indexes in advance. Below I get the first div, then accumulate sibling elements until we hit the next div.clear. (I'll have a think if I can generify this pattern and add it to jsoup.)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(h);
Element firstDiv = doc.select("div.clear").first();
Elements news = new Elements();
Element item = firstDiv.nextElementSibling();
while (item != null && !(item.tagName().equals("div") && item.className().equals("clear"))) {
    news.add(item);
    item = item.nextElementSibling();
}

System.out.println(String.format("Found %s items", news.size()));
for (Element element : news) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Outputs:

```
Found 3 items
W związku z Narodowym Świętem Niepodległości ....
W zeszły p....
OISW Kraków
```

Comment: This is great but the problem is that I don`t know start and stop index. Number of tags is random.

Comment: @masel.popowo I've added another example based on your update